# Format a US address

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source

Your task is to format an address given in all lowercase to a friendlier format. Here's the catch, **no regexes**.

Addresses will be given in the following format:

`123 serpentine pl ne shoreline wa 98199`

The expected output is the following: (notice the period and commas)

`123 Serpentine Pl. NE, Shoreline WA, 98199`

**Formatting Rules**

- Cardinal directions should be capitalized, e.g. "e" --> "E", "nw" -->
  "NW".
- Abbreviations for streets, avenues, etc. should have the first letter
  capitalized with the abbr. followed by a period (".")  e.g "st" --> "St.", "ave" --> "Ave.".
- State abbreviation should be in all caps
- A comma is placed after each section. i.e. after the street address and state and city.
- Capitalize the city and street/avenue/place.

**EDIT**:
Addresses will always be given in the above format *except* with or without a cardinal direction.

Your code should also be able to handle "st" and "ave". The input is given through `stdin`. This is code-golf so the shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Please provide an explanation of the formatting rules that should be used.  It's not at all obvious from your example why "ne" and "wa" should be fully capitalized and followed by commas, while "pl" should have only the first letter capitalized and be followed by a period.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen added rules.

Comment: Could you please provide a full list of `st` `ave` `pl` things?

Comment: Also, will addresses always have this form with all the components `<number> <street> <st/ave/pl> <direction> <city> <state> <zip>`? Or may parts be omitted (e.g. can the address not have a St/Ave/Pl postfix, or a cardinal direction).

Comment: The US Postal Service prefers no punctuation except for the hyphen in 9-digit zip codes and, all caps: http://pe.usps.gov/text/pub28/welcome.htm

Comment: How can Capitalize give NW, Caps give state abbreviation and Capitalize give Serpentine? Can you clarify that? Presumably there are streetnames with more than one element in addition to the description of the stree? And cities with more than one element? Can you include some examples?

Comment: There are a *lot* more possible ways to enter in the given addresses - and a *lot* more possible variations in addresses - than is covered here. For example: `123 Serpentine Place NE, Shoreline Washington 98199` or `123 Serpentine Pl NE, Apartment 6, Shoreline Wa 98199` or `123 Serpentine Pl, 98199`. How do we handle those, or are we to only expect addresses strictly in the formats already given without any more or less detail?

Comment: `1681 broadway new york ny 10036`

Answer (score 6):

## Perl 6: ??? characters

The simplest Perl 6 solution is probably: (*61 characters*)

```
$/=get.wordcase.words;"$0 $1 $2. $3.uc(), $4 $5.uc(), $6".say
```

Unfortunately, I don't feel comfortable using this, since `.wordcase` and `.words` are both implemented internally using regexes. Thus: (also, oddly, *61 characters*)

```
$/=get.split(' ')».tc;"$0 $1 $2. $3.uc(), $4 $5.uc(), $6".say
```

BUT this only handles the specific address given in the problem. Consider:

```
42 awesome ln dogeland hi 96899
```

I see this as valid under to be formatted given the rules above, and this should be formatted as `42 Awesome Ln., Dogeland HI, 96899` rather than `42 Awesome Ln. DOGELAND, Hi 96899,`. So let's fix the case that a cardinal direction isn't included: (*136 characters*)

```
my@a=get.split(" ")».tc;@a[3].=uc if @a[3] eq tc any "n","s","" X~ "e","w","";@a[2]~=".";say "@a[0..*-4], @a[*-3] @a[*-2].uc(), @a[*-1]"
```

Answer (score 1):

## Lua - 462

```
_=_G d={n=_,nw=_,sw=_,s=_,se=_,e=_,ne=_,al=_,ak=_,az=_,ar=_,ca=_,co=_,ct=_,de=_,dc=_,fl=_,ga=_,hi=_,id=_,il=_,["in"]=_,ia=_,ks=_,ky=_,la=_,me=_,md=_,ma=_,mi=_,mn=_,ms=_,mo=_,mt=_,nv=_,nh=_,nj=_,nm=_,ny=_,nd=_,oh=_,ok=_,["or"]=_,pa=_,ri=_,sc=_,sd=_,tn=_,tx=_,ut=_,vt=_,va=_,wa=_,wv=_,wi=_,wy=_}l={pl=_,st=_,ave=_,hw=_}print((io.read"*a":gsub("%w+",function(x)if d[x]then return x:upper()..","end return x:sub(1,1):upper()..x:sub(2):lower()..(l[x]and"."or"")end)))
```

The first is a list of states and directions, the second is a list of places.
One might argue that gsub is using regular expressions, but lua uses *patterns*, that are close, but not exactly are regexes. They cannot match regular languages and don't even have a proper Klenee star.

Example:

```
 $ lua % <<< '123 serpentine pl ne shoreline wa 98199'
 123 Serpentine Pl. NE, Shoreline WA, 98199
```

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript

```
b="123 serpentine pl ne shoreline wa 98199".split(" ");
c=[];
cap = function(l){var code=parseInt(l.charCodeAt(0));if(code>=97&&code<=122){l=String.fromCharCode(code-32);}return l;} 
c[0]=b[0];
c[6]=b[6];
b.forEach(function(txt,index){
 tx=txt.split("");
 switch(index){
     case 1:case 4:tx[0]=cap(tx[0]);c[index]=tx.join("");break;
     case 2:case 3:case 5:tx.forEach(function(t,idx){
            tx[idx]=cap(t);
        });
        c[index]=tx.join("");
        break;
      } 
});

//now
output=c[0]+" "+c[1]+" "+c[2]+". "+c[3]+", "+c[4]+" "+c[5]+", "+c[6];
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python3 <s>137</s> 122

```
i=input().split()
c=lambda x:x.capitalize()
print(i[0],c(i[1]),c(i[2])+".",i[3].upper()+",",c(i[4]),i[5].upper()+",",i[6])
```

```
>python main.py
123 serpentine pl ne shoreline wa 98199  #Pasted
123 Serpentine Pl. NE, Shoreline WA, 98199  #Output
>
```

Comment: I think using `input()` would give you a lower char count (you don't need `sys`) and it would fit the rules better. ("The input is given through `stdin`.")

Answer (score 0):

## Python2

(based on other python3 answer)

```
i=raw_input().split()
i=map(lambda x:x.capitalize(),i)
print " ".join((i[0],i[1],i[2]+".",i[3].upper()+",",i[4] ,i[5].upper()+",",i[6]))
```

running in Windows cmd

```
C:\Python27>python main.py
123 serpentine pl ne shoreline wa 98199 #Pasted
123 Serpentine Pl. NE, Shoreline WA, 98199 #Output
```

Answer (score 0):

## Powershell v4

```
$h=Read-Host
$i=(Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($h).Split()
($i[0..2 ] -join " ")+". "+$i[-4].ToUpper()+", "+$i[-3]+" "+$i[-2].ToUpper()+",",$i[-1]
```

running

```
C:\>powershell .\address.ps1
123 serpentine pl ne shoreline wa 98199 #Pasted
123 Serpentine Pl. NE, Shoreline WA, 98199 #Output
```